Cluster sample or stratified random sample?
I've recently come across this problem in my textbook:

To gather information about the validity of a new standardized test
for high school juniors across the United States, a random sample of
20 high schools were selected from each state. The results from the
new standardized test were recorded for each of these 20 high schools.
What kind of sample is this?

I believed that the answer was a cluster sample, because the "clusters" (high schools) were selected and every student in each high school was tested, but the answer listed was a stratified random sample. The justification given was:

All high schools in the United States are grouped together by state. Then, an SRS is taken from each state to ensure a fair representation from all 50 states.

This explanation seemed to make sense to me as well, but because the high schools were not individuals, I wasn't sure if it would eliminate the possibility of the sample being a cluster sample.
Can someone clear up what's happening here? Which answer is correct, and why?

This kind of questions requires precise definitions of what's being sampled, and often a single survey can have multiple populations studied.
In your context, I believe your textbook gives the correct response, for the information given. The study is interested in test results at school level (not at student level), so therefore the individual of interest is a school.
In the design, stratification has been used to force coverage into every state - so it therefore is stratified.
From the wording, there's no evidence of clustering. If we were interested in the test results of students, and the survey design was (for example) "a random sample of 20 high schools was selected from each state, and the test results of 50 students was randomly sampled from each school", then it would be a stratified (state), clustered (school) sample, with the individual being the student. But that's not the case.
